# UITableView does not have a member named count

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am a new developer to the Swift language so I am trying to making simple UITableview with a static array, what is not working well .
I got this error saying that UITableview does not have any member named count.
What can I do to solve this problem ? 
Thank you in advance
[image: The Wrror]

Comment: Please paste your code directly into your question and use the {} code button rather than screen shots.  It is easier to read and copy into answers

Comment: yes next time i will remeber it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `tableView` is not an array but `myArray` is your array as I can see in your picture so replace `tableView` with `myArray` where you getting errors and I recommended you to read some Docs on `tableView` and on `Array`.

At your First error your code will be:

```
return myArray.count
```

At second error it will be :

```
cell.textLabel?.text = self.myArray[indexPath.row]
```

And at last your code will be:

```
let selectValue = myArray[indexPath.row]
```

Hope it will help you to understand.

Here are some good tutorial on `tableView`:

https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/
http://www.codingexplorer.com/getting-started-uitableview-swift/

Comment: Thank You so much - Dharmesh Kheni

Answer (score 4):

you have to pass your `array` count not `tableView` count

In `numberOfRowInSection`

`return self.myArray.count`

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

`cell.textLabel.text = self.myArray[indexPath.row]`

Comment: @AnkurKathiriya Most Welcome, please accept any of the answer